# Is there a way to create two Classes that needs each other in during their Initialization process?

Tags: c++

I have a program where two classes need each other in their Initialization process, but so far all I get is Compilation Error and I have no idea how to make it work

in Class `MainComponent`

```
class MainComponent  : {
   private:
      PlaylistComponent playlistComponent{formatManager, *this};
}
```

in Class `PlaylistComponent`

```
class PlaylistComponent :{
   private:
      MainComponent& mainComponent;
}
PlaylistComponent::PlaylistComponent(juce::AudioFormatManager &_formatManager, MainComponent &_mainComponent):
formatManager(_formatManager),
mainComponent(_mainComponent){
   //something else
}
```

and here are the error messages:

```
error: ‘MainComponent’ has not been declared
   29 |     PlaylistComponent(juce::AudioFormatManager&, MainComponent&);
error: ‘MainComponent’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘Component’?
   74 |     MainComponent& mainComponent;
error: ‘PlaylistComponent’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘MainComponent’?
   49 |     PlaylistComponent playlistComponent{formatManager, *this};
error: ‘MainComponent’ has not been declared
   29 |     PlaylistComponent(juce::AudioFormatManager&, MainComponent&);

error: could not convert ‘{((MainComponent*)this)->MainComponent::formatManager, (*(MainComponent*)this)}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘PlaylistComponent’
   49 |     PlaylistComponent playlistComponent{formatManager, *this};
      |                                                             ^
      |                                                             |
      |                                                             <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

So far I have tried different approach such as " forward declarations"([Two classes that refer to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994253/two-classes-that-refer-to-each-other)) but it did not work, and the error message was that `playlistComponent` has incomplete type `PlaylistComponent`

I know that it's because one Class needs to be initialized before the other, but how could I do this when both Classes need each other during the Initialization process?

Comment: Show your failed attempt. Make sure it doesn't have any typos (like the code you have now).

Comment: `PlaylistComponent` needs to have its definition available before `MainComponent`, while `MainComponent` only requires a forward declaration for `PlaylistComponent` (since it only declares a reference of the latter). Please make sure your include directives are set up accordingly.

Comment: Here is a compilable example that shows what I mean: https://wandbox.org/permlink/sXXf35yERBxOx2Gu.

Comment: Yes, @Mike is right, add `class PlaylistComponent;` forward declaration before you declare `MainComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this(forward declaration: because you didn't show us how you used forward decleration I show that again here):

```cpp
//in  A.h file
class B;
class A{
    B* b; // or anything else that dont need definition here and just need definition in cpp file.
}
```

```cpp
//in  B.h file
class A;
class B{
    A* a; // or anything else that dont need definition here and just need definition in cpp file.
}
```

```cpp
// in A.cpp 
include "A.h"
include "B.h"
```

```cpp
// in B.cpp 
include "B.h"
include "A.h"
```

> Note: always write the namespaces too if the class has namespace(in
> forward decleration) for example:

```
namespace mine{
class A;
}
```